# Oracle update production database

Tags: sql, oracle, production-environment

Scenario:

- I have a huge .csv file (million of lines) .
- With `sqlldr` (SQL Loader) I have to create a temporary table with all the data in the CSV.
- After this I have to do some processing on the temporary table (uppercase update some columns, etc.).
- After processing, I have to take every row from the temporary table, make some additional checks and insert those rows in another table (being heavily used in production) .

How do you suggest to make all this processing, so that I won't affect the overall performance of the production environment ?

(NOTE: I am not supposed to pre-process the .csv before hand).

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated !

Comment: Is  there a reason you can't load this in development and deploy it from there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know you've said you want to use SQL Loader, but you might want to look at using an external table as it might make things easier.  You could declare your external table as something like

```
create table EXTERNAL_HR_DATA (
    EMPNO    NUMBER(4),
    ENAME    VARCHAR2(10),
    JOB      VARCHAR2(9),
    MGR      NUMBER(4),
    HIREDATE DATE,
    SAL      NUMBER(7,2),
    COMM     NUMBER(7,2),
    DEPTNO   NUMBER(2))
    Organization external
        (type oracle_loader
         default directory testdir
         access parameters (records delimited by newline
                            fields terminated by ‘,’)
         location (‘emp_ext.csv’))
    reject limit 1000;
```

This would allow you to read (but not change) the data in your file using standard SELECT statements.  You could then SELECT from the external table and INSERT the data into your 'temp' table directly, doing at least some of the editing during the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_HR_DATA
  SELECT EMPNO,
         UPPER(TRIM(ENAME)),
         UPPER(TRIM(JOB)),
         MGR,
         HIREDATE,
         SAL,
         COMM,
         DEPTNO
    FROM EXTERNAL_HR_DATA;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I've used external tables for uploading from CSV files - my set was about 100k records, and it was a smooth, painless process. +1

Comment: +1, though not convinced this is any more efficient/performant than SQL*Loader.

Comment: You can't do as much processing in external files as in sqlldr (SQL on a field to update it in a particular way), but it's a good choice if you're trying to use less disk on any of your steps, especially if these would require more temp tables.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if your database has enough diskspace, and isn't too strained on it's RAM/CPU.

If that's OK: just do it. A million of lines isn't spectacular. Loading the file into a work table doesn't sound like something that would normally affect production performance. You could do the to_upper() in your sqlldr control-file (saves you an update on the work table). Maybe there is more post-processing that can be done while loading?

An external table (as suggested in the other answer) works fine as well, but has imho no other advantage than saving some disk space, while it does give some extra hassle to configure (create directory, grant access, transfer file to db server).

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do a fair bit of post-processing in SQL*Loader when you load the file. This could reduce some of the load on the database as updating the temporary table may be slow and create large amounts of redo/undo/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the data and do your processing into your CERT database.  When you've finished processing the temp table move it to PROD w/ export/import (datapump) or over database link.  Then do your insert into the PROD table.  This would let you do your data processing w/o any impact on PROD.  The inserts have to be done in PROD, to minimize impact you should take a look at any triggers/constraints/indexes that can be disabled/dropped during the inserts if you think it'll be a big deal.